# cobalt miss HTMLMediaElement::Load() after play any title randomly?

Tags: cobalt

we got a strange issue that when cobalt play any title, it do not apply HTMLMediaElement::Load(). but it is random, no rule to describe it.

could someone guide us to debug it?
or is possible to debug JS?

[image]

we reproduce it on linux-x64x11_gold also, we got same result.
git version: ef7f901 - (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Import Cobalt 9.34413
suggestion steps:
1. sign in
2. play "6_P8RUqGQbM" and wait advertisement. if no AD, back and replay it to display AD. AD is key point.
3. if AD is showing, wait the button "Skip" to press it.
4. after exit AD, you may see attached picture.if not, try again.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible case? Does this happen on desktop Linux Cobalt?

Comment: hi David, we update more information in this question.

Comment: Hmm, if it is happening in Linux, it seems like it must be a bug in Cobalt. We are about to push to the Open-Source repository again in the next day or two. If it still happens, you should file a bug at the Cobalt issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:181120 status:open

Comment: hi Dvaid, Cobalt 10.49488 can reproduce it on Linux. we file a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37970302. thanks.